# Vim - `=` (equalprg) doesn't use expandtab.

Tags: vim

I am a python developer and I work for a company where the python convention for indentation is two spaces rather than four.

So I notice this problem when I paste code from vim:

This is the text I am trying to paste:

```
def four_spaces():
    print "hello"
```

This text is copied in mac from Chrome using `<cmd> c`. Note that I am using `vim` in iTerm in the Mac OS X.

Below are the steps for me to pasting this in vim using  as I am using a mac:

1. `:set paste` *Turn Paste mode on*
2. `a` *Append mode*
3. `<Cmd> v` *Pasting in Mac*
4. Result shown in **Snippet 4**. *Note that it's 4 spaces*
5. `v kk` *Visual mode to select the above
6. `=` *Fix indentation*
7. Result shown in **Snippet 7**. *Note the ^I*

**Snippet 4 (listmode on)**

```
def four_spaces():$
    print "hello"$
```

**Snippet 7 (listmode on)**

```
def four_spaces():$
^Iprint "hello"$
```

This is what my .vimrc file looks like for those interested:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/20b2a1f43125c0d39932bf430c8137dc

**Problem:**

The problem I am facing with right now is that I have a tab character rather than 2 space when I use `=`. This is problematic because python relies on tab indentation and it cannot allow tab characters and spaces to co-exist together. I am trying to figure out how come = doesn't use expandtab.

**Question:** 
How can I paste using `<Cmd> v` and such that:

1. Vim formats my code properly to 2 spaces
2. *OR* how can I get vim's equalprg (`=`) to use `expandtab`?

Comment: `^I` is tab character. try using `:set nolist` and see if it goes away

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that I have a tab character rather than 2 space. This is problematic because python relies on tab indentation. I am trying to figure out how come = doesn't use expandtab.

Comment: Your `.vimrc` doesn't tell us the whole story if you're using Pathogen. Can you report specifically what `:set sw? ts? sts? et? inde?` says in a Python buffer?

Comment: @Amadan shiftwidth=2, tabstop=3,   softtabstop=2, <nothing> from `set et`, `set inde` returns `  indentexpr=GetPythonPEPIndent(v:lnum)`

Comment: So I think now you have your answer to "how come = doesn't use expandtab" :) Try `:verbose set et?` to see the culprit. (Also, I can't figure out for the life of me why you'd have `ts=3 sts=2`...?!?)

Comment: On a side note: you left your GitHub token in the config you posted.  Does this mean we can start making commits in your name? :)

Comment: @Amadan actually ts=3 is a typo. `ts=2` is the actual answer. This is from :verbose: `  expandtab
        Last set from ~/.vimrc`

Comment: This is strange, "<nothing> from set et" I thought expandtab was unset; it seems it is set after all? Was `:verbose set et?` also done from a Python buffer? My Vim is doing what you expect, so some setting must be different.